# Restrict the role permission to read only

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, permissions, user-roles

I have built my Magento store with the Magento - 1.9.X.X

I am trying to create a role with just read-only permissions to all the modules in the admin end. The user should be able to view all the modules, but not be able to edit them. Is this possible? If yes, can someone kindly tell me how to do that?

Comment: you can create that by `system > permission> roles`.... in some modules they gave options to view only....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have checked there. There are only checkboxes to select the modules that we want to assign to a user that we are creating, which by default provides both read and write permission for that modules to the user. We cannot explicitly define the write or read permissions there.